# Entity Framework invalid object name "dbo.EA_EmployeePerformance"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It is weird since I use the simple membership initialization my EF model cannot create a new table. My code was able to create the new table needed if there is a transaction required for the model.

This is my model :

```
public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
{
    public EmployeeDBContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EmployeeDBContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EmployeeDBContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<EA_Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EA_EmployeePerformance> EmployeePerformances { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EA_EmployeeRank> EmployeeRanks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}

[Table("EA_EmployeePerformance")]
public class EA_EmployeePerformance
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Display(Name = "Employee Performance Id")]
    public int EmployeePerformanceId { get; set; }

    [Index("Performance", IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Required]
    public string Performance { get; set; }

    public EA_EmployeePerformance()
    {
        Performance = "";
    }
}
```

Whenever I SaveChanges(), the DB throws me

> "Invalid object name dbo.EmployeePerformance".

I check the database and the database only contains tables required from simple membership.

How can I auto create the tables when a transaction is occurred for that model?

---

### --------- EDITED ---------

Now I know what is my problem. The problem is because I use multiple dbContext in one database. It is gonna be tricky to do the migration because migration only works on one dbContext isn't it?

So in my case the problem is because the original AccountDBContext from the simple membership is taking over my database, that is why my other dbContext such as the EmployeeDBContext cannot create the new table (please correct me if i'm wrong).

Is there a way for me to keep the multiple dbContexts in a single database?

Comment: your initializer is CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. It seems the database exists, but without the EA_EmployeePerformance table. Drop the database, do a migration or change your initializer in that case.

Comment: My problem is when i called `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);` This code prevents my multiple dbContext to create table in my database (one database for all contexts). How to prevent this while i'm using the simple membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to change your Db Initializer to DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges otherwise, you will still have the old database and you will never get the model changes without deleting the database manually.

> database. It is gonna be tricky to do the migration because migration only works on one dbContext isn't it?

For migration I recommend you to create one DbContext for migration that called for Example MigrationDbContext which contains the the all DbSets and the POCO objects, also when the POCO objects belong to other assembly then just reference them.

Comment: Well, i'm making this project as a module / plugin for my main project, I wanted to be able to inject / changes the main database (main project) from my modules, so I keep only one database for my entire system, but i guess it is better to make multiple databases for each module yes?

Comment: it is depends on your requirements, you can separate them with Db scheme or with multiple databases. Read the bounded contexts apporach https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857357.aspx  and here is the code example https://github.com/julielerman/TEE14Demo each apporach has pros and cons you have to compare your requirements with the available tech.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Migrations, this will help you manage your changes in your code and update the database scheme accordingly.

Here is a guide for how to use it [Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx).